# Getting App Engine Modules to work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, module

I'm learning about Google App Engine modules, but I can't seem to get them running on the dev_appserver, not even by downloading and using their [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python).

According to the sample application, all requests sent to `/work` or `/mobile` would be dispatched to the corresponding module.

However, when I send request to `http://localhost:8080/work` or `http://localhost:8080/mobile`, it returns a 404.

- [app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python/blob/master/app.yaml)
- [dispatch.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python/blob/master/dispatch.yaml)
- [mobile_frontend.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python/blob/master/mobile_frontend.yaml)
- [static_backend.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python/blob/master/static_backend.yaml)

I start the dev_appserver using the command line:

```
dev_appserver.py appengine-modules-helloworld-python-master
```

And I get:

```
INFO     2014-06-23 09:39:16,375 sdk_update_checker.py:242] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2014-06-23 09:39:16,673 sdk_update_checker.py:286] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.
WARNING  2014-06-23 09:39:16,678 api_server.py:378] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-06-23 09:39:16,682 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:61790
INFO     2014-06-23 09:39:16,686 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-06-23 09:39:16,692 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

According to documentation, I should be seeing more lines telling me that the other modules are being started on different ports, but I dont get that for some reason.

Then, if I run the following code:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import modules

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!\n%s\n%s' % (modules.get_modules(), modules.get_hostname()))

APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

It results in:

```
Hello, webapp2 World!
['default']
localhost:8080
```

As if the non-default modules have not been loaded...

Whats the proper way of setting up module and making them work both on local development server as well as in production?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to post your yaml files so we can help.  The sample has url handlers for /work and /mobile. I did not see one for /fun.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Yes, it's /work and /mobile. So the question is, with those YAML files, why when I call those two URLs, it returns a 404 instead of the request being routed to the modules?

Comment: Not enough info.  When you go to `http://localhost:8080`, what do you get?  Can you post your other yaml files, including dispatch.yaml?

Comment: I've edited the post and added all the details. Looks like dev_appserver is not starting the modules...

Comment: Still need to see the yaml files.

Comment: I've posted them as links in the body of my message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong app names in the yaml files.  The names should match what you use when you start the local server in the `dev_appserver.py` command: `appengine-modules-helloworld-python-master`.  Switch it in the command or the yaml files so they match.

You also need to startup the modules in the dev server:

`dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml mobile_frontend.yaml static_backend.yaml`

Comment: Ok, I changed the app directory name to "simple-sample" for it to be the same as the app name in the YAML files. I run `dev_appserver.py simple-sample` and I get the same result as before. No modules are initialized in the startup log, when I send a request to the above URLs /work or /mobile a 404 is returned.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know you had to add the yaml files to the dev_appserver parameters. Works now! Thanks again!